# File not found in Convolutional Neural Network Model

Tags: python-3.x

---

FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
 in

```
  4 import pickle
  5
```

----> 6 X = pickle.load(open("X.pickle", "rb"))

```
  7 y = pickle.load(open("y.pickle", "rb"))
  8
```

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'X.pickle'

Comment: It looks like the file you are trying to open does not exits. Make sure to set the correct path to it, or at least that it is in the same directory with the python file that you are executing.

Comment: should I provide the path of dataset?

Comment: Yes, in the `open` function, if it is not in the same directory as the python file that you are executing.

Comment: It is showing the same error when I am giving the path of dataset

Comment: Is the file named `X.pickle`? With a capial `X`, as you are adding it in your code?

Please check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)